# Returning blank string when scraping sub elements inside </script> tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I am new to python and web scraping. I am trying to scrape a website to obtain a specific element inside a script tag. I am able to scrape the specific tag but I am not sure how to get at the specific element.  From what I understand I need to convert the script to a string and use json.loads to access the specific element. When I use .string to convert my script it returns an nothing. How can I fix this?

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://preply.com/en/skype/english-tutoring-jobs'

r= requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

script = soup.find_all('script')[6].string()


data = json.loads(script)

print(data['url'])
```

The script tag I scraped. I am trying to obtain all the "url" sub elements.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
 {"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"ItemList","url":"https://preply.com/en/skype/english-tutoring-jobs","numberOfItems":18115,"itemListElement":[{"@type":"ListItem","url":"/en/job/646190","position":1,"name":"English language"},{"@type":"ListItem","url":"/en/job/646183","position":2,"name":"\nCommunicative online English lessons are needed with a trained mentor"},{"@type":"ListItem","url":"/en/job/646180","position":3,"name":"\nOnline English learning session with a customised learning plan is needed"},{"@type":"ListItem","url":"/en/job/646177","position":4,"name":"\nOnline English tutor priced up to $8 is needed."},{"@type":"ListItem","url":"/en/job/646174","position":5,"name":"\nOnline teacher who will help me improve my pronunciation in English is wanted."},{"@type":"ListItem","url":"/en/job/646171","position":6,"name":"\nSeek for online tutor priced up to $8 to upgrade my English."},{"@type":"ListItem","url":"/en/job/646166","position":7,"name":"\nI wish to improve my knowledge in English online and receive personalized advice from a experienced mentor"},{"@type":"ListItem","url":"/en/job/646152","position":8,"name":"\nI want to begin English lessons online full of real-world tasks with an organized tutor"},{"@type":"ListItem","url":"/en/job/646138","position":9,"name":"\nWant to find online teacher priced near $10 to improve my English."},{"@type":"ListItem","url":"/en/job/646134","position":10,"name":" \nInstructor is wanted for online English tutoring job"},{"@type":"ListItem","url":"/en/job/646123","position":11,"name":"\nOnline English training with a tailored methodology is demanded"},{"@type":"ListItem","url":"/en/job/646122","position":12,"name":"\nNeed to find an online instructor to learn English with proper tests of my progress"},{"@type":"ListItem","url":"/en/job/646121","position":13,"name":"\nOnline English teacher priced below $16 is wanted."},{"@type":"ListItem","url":"/en/job/646110","position":14,"name":"\nLooking for help in studying English from a qualified teacher online"},{"@type":"ListItem","url":"/en/job/646109","position":15,"name":"\nCommunicative online English classes are needed with a trained coach"},{"@type":"ListItem","url":"/en/job/646103","position":16,"name":"\nCommunicative online English learning sessions are required with a experienced mentor"},{"@type":"ListItem","url":"/en/job/646102","position":17,"name":"\nNeed online tutor priced near $16 to upgrade my English."},{"@type":"ListItem","url":"/en/job/646092","position":18,"name":"\nI need to have lessons online with a positive English instructor who will assign me various activities"},{"@type":"ListItem","url":"/en/job/646087","position":19,"name":"\nOnline English teacher priced around $24 is wanted."},{"@type":"ListItem","url":"/en/job/646080","position":20,"name":"\nI would like to begin learning sessions online with a caring English professor who will give me different tasks"}]}
</script>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: first you could use `print()` to check what you get in `soup.find_all('script')[6]` without `string`, next check with `string` but without `()`. As I know BS doesn't have `string()` but `string` or `text` or `get_text()`

Comment: What version of BeautifulSoup do you have that allows you to call `.string()`?

Comment: do you really get empty string ? I get error message when I use `.string()` because it has to be `.string` without `()`. And I get empty string when I use `.text` or `.get_text()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all url are in under `itemListElement`. try this.

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://preply.com/en/skype/english-tutoring-jobs'

r= requests.get(url)
print(r.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

script = soup.find_all('script')[6].string

data = json.loads(script)

for urls in data['itemListElement']:
    print(urls['url'])
```

Comment: Thanks Samsul Islam, this is exactly to outcome I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Code works for me if I use `.string` instead of `.string()`.

It gives me: `https://preply.com/en/skype/english-tutoring-jobs`

---

If I use `.string()` then I don't get empty string but error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 23, in <module>
    script = soup.find_all('script')[6].string()
TypeError: 'Script' object is not callable
```

---

I get empty string when I use `.get_text()` or `.text` instead of `.string`

---

Tested with: Beautifulsoup 4.9.1, Python 3.8.5, Linux Mint 20

---

**EDIT:**

I find out that `.text` and `.get_text()` can give script text only for `html5lib`

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
```

Comment: You are correct, part of my problem was that I was using .string() and not .string. I'm still very new to this. Thank you for your help!